# Calculate distance between arrays that contain NaN

Tags: python, numpy

consider `array1` and `array2`, with:

```
array1 = [a1 a2 NaN ... an]
array2 = [[NaN b2 b3 ... bn],
          [b21 NaN b23 ... b2n],
          ...]
```

Both arrays are numpy-arrays. There is an easy way to compute the Euclidean distance between `array1`and each row of `array2`:

```
EuclideanDistance = np.sqrt(((array1 - array2)**2).sum(axis=1))
```

What messes up this computation are the NaN values. Of course, I could easily replace NaN with some number. But instead, I want to do the following:

When I compare `array1` with `row_x` of `array2`, I count the columns in which one of the arrays has NaN and the other doesn't. Let's assume the `count` is 3. I will then delete these columns from both arrays and compute the Euclidean distance between the two. In the end, I add a `minus_value * count` to the calculated distance.

Now, I cannot think of a fast and efficient way to do this. Can somebody help me?

Here are a few of my ideas:

```
minus = 1000
dist = np.zeros(shape=(array1.shape[0])) # this array will store the distance of array1 to each row of array2
array1 = np.repeat(array1, array2.shape[0], axis=0) # now array1 has the same dimensions as array2
for i in range(0, array1.shape[0]):
    boolarray = np.logical_or(np.isnan(array1[i]), np.isnan(array2[i]))
    count = boolarray.sum()
    deleteIdxs = boolarray.nonzero() # this should give the indices where boolarray is True
    dist[i] = np.sqrt(((np.delete(array1[i], deleteIdxs, axis=0) - np.delete(array2[i], deleteIdxs, axis=0))**2).sum(axis=0))
    dist[i] = dist[i] + count*minus
```

These lines look more than ugly to me, however. Also, I keep getting an index error: Apparently deleteIdxs contains an index that is out of range for array1. Don't know how this can even be.

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what's the problem with the nan values. Why not compute the distance (maybe using `np.linalg.norm` instead of doing it manually) and then simply ignore the nans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function to handle the distance calculation. I am sure there is a faster and more efficient way to write this (list comprehensions, aggregations, etc.), but readability counts, right? :)

```py
import numpy as np
def calculate_distance(fixed_arr, var_arr, penalty):
    s_sum = 0.0
    counter = 0
    for num_1, num_2 in zip(fixed_arr, var_arr):
        if np.isnan(num_1) or np.isnan(num_2):
            counter += 1
        else:
            s_sum += (num_1 - num_2) ** 2
    return np.sqrt(s_sum) + penalty * counter, counter


array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.NaN, 5, 6])
array2 = np.array(
    [
        [3, 4, 9, 3, 4, 8],
        [3, 4, np.NaN, 3, 4, 8],
        [np.NaN, 9, np.NaN, 3, 4, 8],
        [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    ]
)
dist = np.zeros(len(array2))


minus = 10
for index, arr in enumerate(array2):
    dist[index], _ = calculate_distance(array1, arr, minus)

print(dist)
```

You have to think about the value for the **minus** variable very carefully. Is adding a random value really useful?

As @Nathan suggested, a more resource efficient can easily be implemented.

```py
fixed_arr = array1
penalty = minus
dist = [
    (
        lambda indices=(np.isnan(fixed_arr) + np.isnan(var_arr)): np.linalg.norm(
            fixed_arr[~indices] - var_arr[~indices]
        )
        + (indices == True).sum() * penalty
    )()
    for var_arr in array2
]
print(dist)
```

However I would only try to implement something like this if I absolutely **needed** to (if it's the bottleneck). For all other times I would be happy to sacrifice some resources in order to gain some readability and extensibility.

Comment: cool, thx very much! ... I know, I am not sure if adding this minus value will do me any good. But I have got to try it out

Comment: What's the point of using arrays if you're going to iterate over them? I suggest using @QuangHoang s answer which will be orders of magnitude faster

Comment: You are absolutely right. I edited my answer to reflect the possibility of using masks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the indices with where the value is nan using:

```
indices_1 = np.isnan(array1)
indices_2 = np.isnan(array2)
```

Which you can combine to:

```
indices_total = indices_1 + indices_2
```

And you can keep all the not nan values using:

```
array_1_not_nan = array1[~indices_total]
array_2_not_nan = array2[~indices_total]
```

Comment: Hey Nathan, thx for your answer! ... is it possible to access all the elements of array1 where `boolarr == TRUE` with `array1[boolarr]`, where `boolarr = np.logical_and.reduce((np.isscalar(array1), np.isscalar(array2[i]), ~boolarray))` ?

Comment: I mean: I tried this out, but apparently `array1[boolarr]` returns an empty list only

Comment: @luk the original answer only returned the correct indices, I've fixed it so that it returns the values of the arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the columns containing `nan` with:

```
mask1 = np.isnan(arr1)
mask2 = np.isnan(arr2).any(0)

mask = ~(mask1 | mask2)

# the two filtered arrays
arr1[mask], arr2[mask]
```